# How to combine filter and map in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter

I have `List[Int]` in Scala. The List is `List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`. I want to `filter` the list so that it only has even numbers. And I want to multiply the numbers with 2.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try using `collect`, it combines features of `filter` and `map`.

Comment: I am looking into it right now. Can you please give an example. The documentation says `partial function` and I dont know what it means.

Comment: Partial function means a function that is defined only in a subset of all possible inputs, which won't return any result when the input is outside this subset. See here for more: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-use-partial-functions-in-scala-syntax-examples

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As I state in my comment, `collect` should do what you want:

```
list.collect{
  case x if x % 2 == 0 => x*2
}
```

The `collect` method allows you to both specify a criteria on the matching elements (`filter`) and modify the values that match (`map`)

And as @TravisBrown suggested, you can use `flatMap` as well, especially in situations where the condition is more complex and not suitable as a guard condition.  Something like this for your example:

```
list.flatMap{
  case x if x % 2 == 0 => Some(x*2)
  case x => None
}
```

Comment: It's not always possible or convenient to phrase your condition in such a way that it will work as a guard, so (IMO) a good answer should include `flatMap` with `Option` (which is also just such a common idiom in Scala that it's useful to recognize).

Comment: @TravisBrown, good point.  I included it as an option in my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: So what will be the size of my final list, 5 or 10?

Comment: @eddard.stark, your final list will have a size of 5 when done

Comment: There is also `withFilter`,  which, compared to `filter().map()`, avoids one iteration and the creation of a filtered list as intermediate step: `list.withFilter(_ % 2 == 0).map(_ * 2)`

Answer (score 13):

A for comprehension (which internally unfolds into a combination of `map` and `withFilter`) as follows,

```
for (x <- xs if x % 2 == 0) yield x*2
```

Namely

```
xs.withFilter(x => x % 2 == 0).map(x => x*2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work for you:

Filter first when the condition is `p % 2 == 0` (for getting only even numbers).

And then use `map` to multiply those even numbers by 2.

```
var myList = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).filter(p => p % 2 == 0).map(p => {p*2})
```

Comment: I tend to downvote all code-only answers that I see, but the "How to combine" part of the title means that this isn't even really an answer.

Comment: I have upvoted you.
Not I was looking for. THank you.

Comment: @travisBrown you should give 30 seconds to edit my answer :) I added the explanation now.

Comment: @cacho It's nothing personal, but I also don't think placeholder answers are a particularly good idea. :)

Comment: fair enough http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166663/how-do-we-feel-about-placeholder-answers-to-indicate-we-are-working-on-an-answer I never got multiple downvotes so quick, good to know.

Answer (score 2):

As @cmbaxter said, collect suits your need perfectly. The other nice thing about collect is that it figures out resulting type in case you're filtering by class:

```
scala> trait X
// defined trait X

scala> class Foo extends X
// defined class Foo

scala> class Bar extends X
// defined class Bar

scala> val xs = List(new Foo, new Bar, new Foo, new Bar)
// xs: List[X] = List(Foo@4cfa8227, Bar@78226c36, Foo@3f685162, Bar@11f406f8)

scala> xs.collect { case x: Foo => x }
// res1: List[Foo] = List(Foo@4cfa8227, Foo@3f685162)
```

On par, filter can't be that smart (see `List[Foo]` vs `List[X]`):

```
scala> xs.filter { case x: Foo => true; case _ => false }
// res3: List[X] = List(Foo@4cfa8227, Foo@3f685162)
```

Comment: Just a quick guess, but I think this is because `{ case x: Foo => x }` is typed as a `PartialFunction[X, Foo]`. `Foo` is the only possible return type, so `collect` already knows it has to build a List that can contain `Foo`s. `filter`, on the other hand, does not have such typing knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to like the filter approach.

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
list1.filter(x => x%2 == 0).map(_*2)
```

Comment: How is this materially different from the answers offered by elm or cacho 2 years ago?

Comment: @jwvh thanks for the comment. It is a slightly different approach. It's a matter of preference that's why I used the phrase "tend to like". I posted the response now because I had this question too and thought others in future have the benefit of looking at different options.

Comment: But it's not a different option. It's exactly the same as cacho's suggestion. The only difference is the use of the underscore in the `map` lambda. Why you don't do the same in the `filter` lambda is also curious.

Comment: I think `collect` and `withFilter` are more performant than this, `filter` and `map` will iterate the array two times.

Answer (score 1):

How about a good old fashioned fold?

```
xs.foldLeft(List[Y]()) { (ys, x) => 
    val z = calculateSomethingOnX(x)
    if (someConditionOnZ(z)) 
        Y(x, z) :: ys
    else 
        ys
}
```