# What is the most efficient way to iterate a collection in parallel in Scala (TOP N pattern)

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

I am new to Scala and would like to build a real-time application to match some people. For a given Person, I would like to get the TOP 50 people with the highest matching score.

The idiom is as follows :

```
val persons = new mutable.HashSet[Person]() // Collection of people
/* Feed omitted */
val personsPar = persons.par // Make it parall
val person = ... // The given person

res = personsPar
        .filter(...) // Some filters
        .map{p => (p,computeMatchingScoreAsFloat(person, p))}
        .toList
        .sortBy(-_._2)
        .take(50)
        .map(t => t._1 + "=" + t._2).mkString("\n")
```

In the sample code above, HashSet is used, but it can be any type of collection, as I am pretty sure it is not optimal

The problem is that persons contains over 5M elements, the computeMatchingScoreAsFloat méthods computes a kind a correlation value with 2 vectors of 200 floats. This computation takes ~2s on my computer with 6 cores.

My question is, what is the fastest way of doing this TOPN pattern in Scala ?

Subquestions :
- What implementation of collection (or something else?) should I use ?
- Should I use Futures ?

**NOTE:** It has to be computed in parallel, the pure computation of computeMatchingScoreAsFloat alone (with no ranking/TOP N) takes more than a second, and < 200 ms if multi-threaded on my computer

**EDIT:** Thanks to Guillaume, compute time has been decreased from 2s to 700ms

```
def top[B](n:Int,t: Traversable[B])(implicit ord: Ordering[B]):collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[B] = {

  val starter = collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[B]()(ord.reverse) // Need to reverse for us to capture the lowest (of the max) or the greatest (of the min)

  t.foldLeft(starter)(
    (myQueue,a) => {
      if( myQueue.length <= n ){ myQueue.enqueue(a);myQueue}
      else if( ord.compare(a,myQueue.head) < 0  ) myQueue
      else{
        myQueue.dequeue
        myQueue.enqueue(a)
        myQueue
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you benchmarked this? Is computeMatchingScoreAsFloat the most expensive part? Is it heavy enough to be worth parallelizing?

Comment: Yes, It has to be computed in parallel, the pure computation of computeMatchingScoreAsFloat (with no ranking/TOP N) takes more than a second, and 40 ms if multi threaded on my computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would propose a few changes:

1- I believe that the filter and map steps requires traversing the collection twice. Having a lazy collection would reduce it to one. Either have a lazy collection (like Stream) or converting it to one, for instance for a list:

```
myList.view
```

2- the sort step requires sorting all elements. Instead, you can do a FoldLeft with an accumulator storing the top N records. See there for an example of an implementation:
[Simplest way to get the top n elements of a Scala Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674741/simplest-way-to-get-the-top-n-elements-of-a-scala-iterable) . I would probably test a Priority Queue instead of a list if you want maximum performance (really falling into its wheelhouse). For instance, something like this:

```
  def IntStream(n:Int):Stream[(Int,Int)] = if(n == 0) Stream.empty else (util.Random.nextInt,util.Random.nextInt) #:: IntStream(n-1)

  def top[B](n:Int,t: Traversable[B])(implicit ord: Ordering[B]):collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[B] = {

    val starter = collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[B]()(ord.reverse) // Need to reverse for us to capture the lowest (of the max) or the greatest (of the min)

    t.foldLeft(starter)(
      (myQueue,a) => {
        if( myQueue.length <= n ){ myQueue.enqueue(a);myQueue}
        else if( ord.compare(a,myQueue.head) < 0  ) myQueue
        else{
          myQueue.dequeue
          myQueue.enqueue(a)
          myQueue
        }
      }
    )
  }

def diff(t2:(Int,Int)) =  t2._2
 top(10,IntStream(10000))(Ordering.by(diff)) // select top 10
```

I really think that you problem requires a **SINGLE** collection traverse so you be able to get your run time down to below 1 sec

Good luck!

Comment: Thank for your help, I will test this and tell you back the new compute time

Comment: It seems that I can't have a view on a parallel collection (a collection that is both parallel and lazy), I can handle a ParSeq xor a SeqView. Do you know how I can achieve this ? Is there any ParSeqView in Scala ?

Comment: Have you tried running it on a non-parallel collection? I think it has parallel collections have significant overheads and may not be justified (plus, you have a "toList" which, I suspect, merge into a non-parallel collection). Otherwise, you can run a flatMap to combine filter and map (see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234132/how-to-combine-filter-and-map-in-scala) that would effectively be the same result as a lazy collection

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated my original post. And Yes I have already test the computeMatchingScoreAsFloat  computation alone, and it takes> 1s on a non-par collection and < 200 ms on a par collection

Comment: 2s -> 700 ms with your code.
Any other advices ?
I will try to manually split my data into buckets and run multi-threaded computations without any collection methods.

Comment: You need to take out the "toList". This is a slow step on a large collection. Try to run the "top" method on each parallel partition and merge those PriorityQueue into a single one.