# Finding common strings from map type and array Scala without loops

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections

I am trying to find the common strings in a map and an array to output the respective **value**s(from map, values here is Map[key -> **value**]) in Scala, I'm trying to not use any loops. Example:

Input:

```
Array("Ash","Garcia","Mac") Map("Ash" -> 5, "Mac" -> 4, "Lucas" -> 3)
```

Output:

```
Array(5,4)
```

The output is an array with 5 and 4 because Ash and Mac are common in both the data structures

Comment: This does not seem anything like `Java`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.filter` to find the matching entries only, then get the value of your filtered map.

**Given**

```
scala> val names = Array("Ash","Garcia","Mac")
names: Array[String] = Array(Ash, Garcia, Mac)

scala> val nameToNumber = Map("Ash" -> 5, "Mac" -> 4, "Lucas" -> 3)
nameToNumber: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Ash -> 5, Mac -> 4, Lucas -> 3)
```

**`.filter.map`**

```
scala> nameToNumber.filter(x => names.contains(x._1)).map(_._2)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(5, 4)
```

**Alternatively, [you can use `collect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32234177/432903),**

```
scala> nameToNumber.collect{case kv if names.contains(kv._1) => kv._2}
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(5, 4)
```

Your complexity here is `O(n2)`

Answer (score 3):

What constitutes a loop?

```
def common(arr: Array[String], m: Map[String,Int]): Array[Int] =
  arr flatMap m.get
```

Usage:

```
common(Array("Ash","Garcia","Mac")
      ,Map("Ash" -> 5, "Mac" -> 4, "Lucas" -> 3))
// res0: Array[Int] = Array(5, 4)
```

Comment: @AshwinPraveen how can you traverse collection without iterating over?

Comment: @prayagupd I'm sorry, bad phrasing I guess. I just meant that I want to avoid the use of looping structures like "for" "while" "foreach"

Comment: This solution is significantly faster than map.filter one, because it has linear complexity:O(array.size), rather than O(map.size * array.size).

Answer (score 3):

This is the most elegant solution, I think, but the results may not fit your requirements if there are duplicates in the array.

```
yourArray.collect(yourMap) // Array(5,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Quite easy for scala elegant syntax：**

```
val a = Array("Ash","Garcia","Mac")
val m = Map("Ash" -> 5, "Mac" -> 4, "Lucas" -> 3)
println(m.filter { case (k, v) => a.contains(k)}.map { case (k, v) => v}.toArray)
```

**Here is the solution！**