# Scala: Most efficient way to process files in folder based on a file list

Tags: scala, loops, recursion, functional-programming, nested-loops

I am trying to find the most efficient way to process files in multiple folders based on a list of allowed files.

I have a list of allowed files that I should process.

The proces is as follows

1. `val allowedFiles = List("File1.json","File2.json","File3.json")`
2. Get list of folders in directory. For this I could use:

```
      def getListOfSubDirectories(dir: File): List[String] =
            dir.listFiles
               .filter(_.isDirectory)
               .map(_.getName)
               .toList
```

3. Loop through each folder from step 2. and get all files. For this I would use :

```
    def getListOfFiles(dir: String):List[File] = {
        val d = new File(dir)
        if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
            d.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
        } else {
            List[File]()
        }
    }
```

4. If file from step 3. are in list of allowed files call another method that process the file

So I need to loop through a first directory, get files, check if file need to be procssed and then call another functionn. I was thinking about double loop which would work but is the most efficient way. I know in scala I should be using resursive funstions but failed with this double recursive function with call to extra method.

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Files.find()` will do both the depth search and filter.

```
import java.nio.file.{Files,Paths,Path}
import scala.jdk.StreamConverters._

def getListOfFiles(dir: String, targets:Set[String]): List[Path] =
  Files.find( Paths.get(dir)
            , 999
            , (p, _) => targets(p.getFileName.toString)
            ).toScala(List)
```

usage:

```
val lof = getListOfFiles("/DataDir",  allowedFiles.toSet)
```

But, depending on what kind of processing is required, instead of returning a `List` you might just process each file as it is encountered.

```
import java.nio.file.{Files,Paths,Path}

def processFile(path: Path): Unit = ???
  
def processSelected(dir: String, targets:Set[String]): Unit =
  Files.find( Paths.get(dir)
            , 999
            , (p, _) => targets(p.getFileName.toString)
            ).forEach(processFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Files.walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...))
The code would look like this *(I didn't compile it, so it may have some typos)*

```scala
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path}
import scala.jdk.StreamConverters._

def getFilesRecursive(initialFolder: Path, allowedFiles: Set[String]): List[Path] =
  Files
    .walk(initialFolder)
    .filter(path => allowedFiles.contains(path.getFileName.toString.toLowerCase))
    .toScala(List)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on Scala (last time I dabbled in it was probably 18 years ago) but I figured there had to be a way to take this code:

```scala
def getListOfSubDirectories(dir: File): List[String] =
    dir.listFiles
       .filter(_.isDirectory)
       .map(_.getName)
       .toList
```

And eliminate at least one extra list creation. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234132/how-to-combine-filter-and-map-in-scala) which was instructive, and then did a Google search for `withFilter`.

Looks like you can take that bit above and translate it to the following. By replacing `filter` with `withFilter`, a new list is not created and then iterated over.

```scala
def getListOfSubDirectories(dir: File): List[String] =
    dir.listFiles
       .withFilter(_.isDirectory)
       .map(_.getName)
       .toList
```

Comment: `Streams` are lazy so they only iterate once and mix all the transformations / filters in a single loop.

Comment: 18 years ago? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)) it first appeared in 2004. You must have been in on the pre-pre-release. ;-)

Comment: You should be impressed I got _that_ close without looking it up! I just knew it was a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks for great tips, I will be testing it today